# Return Index of a Value within Pandas Series

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to convert units within a Pandas Series.

```
df["he"] returns a Pandas Series:

    0        5'10"
    1        5'2"
    ...
```

The below variable `num1` should extract the number **5**. Whereas `num2` should extract the number **7**.

The code works for `5'7"` but wouldn't work for `5'10"`

How can I change from `x[2:]` to something that would extract everything before `'`?

In the past I have used functions like `index()` and `find()` - however, I'm new to Pandas and struggling to know how I can implement these.

```
def conversion(x):

    num1 = int(x[:1])
    num2 = int(x[2:3])

    return (num1 * 12 + num2) * 2.54

df["he"] = df["he"].apply(conversion)
```

Comment: could you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58174507/edit) your post to add a sample of your data?

Comment: as a general advise, use the `split` method of string. something like `x.split("'")`

Comment: Thanks. Although not entirely sure how I would implement this. I'm also not sure how I would extract the 10 within 5'10" using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your values are in string format. Split is a great string method to accomplish your task.

```
def conversion(x):
    spl = x.split("'")

    num1 = int(spl[0])
    num2 = int(spl[1])

    return (num1 * 12 + num2) * 2.54
```

Comment: Ahh okay - yes this works great. However, it doesn't currently work as num2 returns 10". Is there a simple way to remove this? Edit - remove the " I mean.

Comment: Actually I worked it out - I just utilised the replace() function to replace the " with nothing.